# Reading Lotus Notes Inbox Messages using VB.Net "Interop.Domino.dll"

Tags: vb.net, lotus-notes

How can I read Lotus Notes Inbox Messages using VB.Net?

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate a session object. Use that object to get a handle on the mail database object (in Lotusscript you would do this for the current user ID by invoking the `NotesDatabase.OpenMail` method—otherwise, open the database in the usual way. There is an equivalent method in COM), and then declare a view object. Set that view object to the `($Inbox)` folder.

This stuff is all documented. The key here is which mail file you need to process I guess, but your question is scant on detail.